CoreData relationship memory use
I have a CoreData model with two entities.  EntityA has a to-many relationship with EntityB, and a reverse to-one relationship the other way.
I have code that imports external data (a text file) into these entities.  It's a large file, that will generate hundreds of thousands (if not millions) of records.
I noticed an increase in memory consumption with each import iteration.  This is due to the way CoreData manages relationships (see here for some good details).
I keep the memory down if I don't set the relationship - but I want the relationship.
The memory can be released by faulting the objects with code like:
context.refresh(newRelatedObjectInEntityB, mergeChanges: false)
that works, but requires a context.save() beforehand so the object isn't lost.  The context.save() (understandably) takes a lot of time.  I was previously batching the saves.
So, I'm faced with an import that either takes a massive amount of memory, or takes a ton of time.
Any suggestions on ways to manage memory use without the slowdown?

I've found a solution that works in my use case.  Sharing should it help others.  I went back to my batch saving, and did a context.reset() after the save.  Resetting the context can cause other issues, but it's fine for my use here.  So, something like this:
// (Code to create the objects and relationships here)
insertCount += 1 // an INT var set to zero before the loop
if insertCount.isMultiple(of: 1000) {
   do {
      try context.save()
      context.reset()
   } catch {
      assertionFailure("Error saving")
   }
}

